# How to get HTTP status message in (py)curl?

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl, http-status

spending some time studying pycurl and libcurl documentation, i still can't find a (simple) way, how to get HTTP status message (reason-phrase) in pycurl.

status code is easy:

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO

curl = pycurl.Curl()
buff = cStringIO.StringIO()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.org')
curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buff.write)
curl.perform()

print "status code: %s" % curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
# -> 200

# print "status message: %s" % ???
# -> "OK"
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

i've found a solution myself, which does what i need, but could be more robust (works for HTTP).

it's based on a fact that captured headers obtained by `pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION` include the status line.

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO
import re

curl = pycurl.Curl()

buff = cStringIO.StringIO()
hdr = cStringIO.StringIO()

curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.org')
curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, buff.write)
curl.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, hdr.write)
curl.perform()

print "status code: %s" % curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
# -> 200

status_line = hdr.getvalue().splitlines()[0]
m = re.match(r'HTTP\/\S*\s*\d+\s*(.*?)\s*$', status_line)
if m:
    status_message = m.groups(1)
else:
    status_message = ''

print "status message: %s" % status_message
# -> "OK"
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an old thread but I got here looking for similar information. If it is just the status code you're looking for, such as 200, 404, 500 etc. then just do:

`your_curl_handle.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE)`

which should return a numerical status code :)

Comment: This is the right way of checking for a status code

Comment: I am getting `pycurl.error: cannot invoke getinfo() - no curl handle` error.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use human_curl library to create you code simple.

```
>>> import human_curl as hurl
>>> r = hurl.get('http://example.org')
>>> print r.status_code
200
```

Full documentation on human_curl you can get on https://github.com/Lispython/human_curl

Comment: "reason-phrase" is a term used by the HTTP protocol documention to refer to the human readable string that comes after the status_code. This example just returns the numeric status code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the code, you can do, and assuming your `pycurl.Curl()` instance is called `curl` (ie. `curl = pycurl.Curl()`), you can do

```
curl.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE)
```

```
curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
```

But the nice way in my opinion is to parse the header yourself instead of letting libraries spoon-feed you everything.

Answer (score -1):

Try BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.responses, it should contain an errorcode dictionnary as explained in [this page](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html#error-codes).

hope this helps.

Comment: that's a possible solution.. i should have pointed out, that i want to have the status message from the server, which may be different, than the standardized one